# Heartbeat in Java: timerTask or thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to implement a very simple client to server heartbeat in java.  The most simple approach seems to be through sleep.  Consider the **metacode** below.

```
class MyClass

    Thread heartbeatThread = new Thread();

    public void() startHeartBeat{
         Thread.sleep(4000);
         sock.write("H");
      }
```

Is this an adequate solution, or are there pitfalls I'm not considering?

I've also considered using the `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` approach.  Would this be more robust/reliable?  If so, why?  Here's an example (it's not as clean IMO):

```
class HeartBeat
{
    Timer timer=new Timer();

    public void scheduleHeartBeat(int delay, int period) {
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new HeartBeatTask(), delay, period);     
       }
}   

class HeartBeatTaskextends TimerTask {
     public void run() {
     sock.write("H");     
}
```

Will the second approach be granted higher priority?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Adequate?  It's adequate if it meets your needs and it's easy to understand.  Looks pretty simple to me, but does it meet your needs?  (See Nathan Hughes's answer for reasons why it _might_ not.)

Comment: I guess I should have used "best practice" instead of "adequate".  I often find it adequate to change all the file permissions on my computer to  777 for example...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, your `Thread`-based idiom will not schedule at fixed rate without an infinite loop.

That's one disadvantage too: you probably want to set some condition to exit the loop.

You also need to catch `InterruptedException` when invoking static `Thread.sleep`.

Another popular idiom for scheduled execution is by using a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

---

Find the 3 alternatives below:

**Timer**

```
// says "foo" every half second
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}, 0, 500);
```

- **Pros**: simple
- **Cons**:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29).

---

**Infinite loop**

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            // Says "blah" every half second
            System.out.println("blah");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // nope
            }
        }
    }
}.start();
```

- **Pros**: super simple. You can vary your recurring delay programmatically.
- **Cons**: `Thread.sleep` is still

> subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. 
>   ... and requires catching `InterruptedException`.

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

Also:

- your infinite loop might require a (somehow potentially cumbersome) breaking condition
- no initial delay setting unless applied manually before infinite loop, which would require another `try` / `catch`.

---

**Executors**

```
ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
es.scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Says "bar" every half second
            System.out.println("bar");
        }
    }, 
    0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

- **Pros**: this is the most recent feature of the 3. Very simple and elegant - you can also schedule `Callable`s (not at fixed rate though) and re-use the `ExecutorService`. The documentation for `java.util.Timer` actually mentions `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (implementing the `ScheduledExecutorService` interface) as a "more versatile replacement for the `Timer`/`TimerTask` combination".
- **Cons** as documented:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late,

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice answer.  Are these executors supplanting methods like timer.scheduleAtFixedRate?  IE scheduledExecutorService is an extension of the older Timer methods?   Can how do I break out of an exector?  Using es.start() / es.stop()?

Comment: @AdamHughes you're welcome. Yes `ScheduledExecutorService`s provide fixed rate (and fixed **delay**) execution. You shut them down by invoking variants of `shutDown`. You can also submit `Runnable`s and `Callable`s (for tasks that return a value). See full docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for general `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Regarding the infinite loop, the try/catch should surround the while loop rather than being inside it.  This way, an interrupt terminates the loop as it should.

Comment: I see there's shutdown methods and submit methods.  Am I right in assuming submit will begin the task?  IE functions like start?   Or does the task start running at instantiation of the `es` variable?

Comment: @VGR I disagree, having the `try` / `catch` outside opens the scope unnecessarily. Which is demonstrated by the fact that you can catch two different interrupts, one outside and one inside, respectively for the initial delay and for the recurring delay.

Comment: @AdamHughes nope. They only submit the tasks for execution (and return a `Future` object). I recommend keeping the docs at hand and reading the API, it's relatively simple.

Comment: Why would the length of the delay matter?  An interrupt means some other code is asking you to gracefully terminate your run method, regardless.

Comment: @VGR who said the length of the delay matters (hint: not me!). An interrupt within your `while` loop execution is scoped (slightly) differently from an interrupt outside your `while` loop: you can have an initial delay outside the `while` loop prior to cycled execution that will require handling an interrupt, whereas an interrupt of the recurring delay for the cycled execution can be handled in its own scope. That's why ideally you'd have a `try` / `catch` outside, *not* including the loop, and one inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the sleep approach, there are some issues to consider.

One is that the sleep time isn't exact, and you could have drift over time (maybe while your thread is sleeping another application hogs CPU and it takes longer than expected for your thread to send its heartbeat, now the next time the thread sends a heartbeat is delayed), your sleep time will be augmented by various things incrementally (you won't sleep for less than your sleep time but may frequently sleep for a bit more), and those increments will add up over time.

Another is that you could have a problem with the socket, you would have to write code to handle making a new connection.

The thread would need to be well-behaved and respond to interruption, or else be a daemon thread. If it had to share data across threads you'd need to be aware of memory visibility issues.

Using a timer would mean each launching of a task would have a fresh start and you wouldn't be vulnerable to accumulated delays or stale network connections.

Comment: Thanks.  Once the CPU hogging subsided, shouldn't the operation get back on track?  Or would the delays be cumulative?  Can you elaborate on the socket bit?  You're saying because socket is shared in my heartbeat thread there's a problem?

Comment: @Adam:  if you depend on sleep i don't know how you get back on track, you're just trusting things will even out. also all network connections are transient and at risk of going bad, but you don't show how that will work. speaking of sharing the timer approach handles that better than using raw threads, where you have to deal with JMM issues. The timer seems more predictable.

Comment: @AdamHughes, delays are cumulative.  `Thread.sleep(n)` is guaranteed to sleep for _at least_ `n` milliseconds if it is not interrupted.  "At least" means, could be a bit more some times.  Those "bit mores" will add up.  Also, your thread will use a bit of time _between_ each sleep call, and those bits will add up too.  If you need a program to do something at precisely regular intervals, then it must check the real-time clock before each sleep and _compute_ how long to sleep until the next event is due.  That's what `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(...)` does for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't know how timers are implemented internally, but what I do understand here is, if you use sleep, you will have to handle InterruptedException, and eating up that exception may not be a good practice. moreover timer tasks would be running within its thread space, and you have better control over it.

You can stop the timer any time if you want, In this case, you may not be able to do that

Comment: Re: ...`InterruptedException`..., a lot of programs are not required to handle interrupts.  In which case, it doesn't really matter.  Some programs are required to shut down on interrupt, in which case, a watchdog thread only needs to die in the handler.  If it's one of those rare programs where some more sophisticated response is required, then it probably won't be adequate to just let the `Timer` thread deal with the interruption anyway.

Comment: Yeah, true. I think in driver in such scenarios should be whether you want synchronous processing or not. If you want the thread to come back to you after sleep, then use Thread.sleep, if the timer job and invoker are not dependent on each other, then its better to start a timer and forget.